# How to test for halides without ammoniacal silver nitrate solution?

Tags: halides, elements

If I have an halide e.g magnesium iodide, how can I test what halide the compound contains?

I understand there is a method using silver nitrate and ammonia but what other methods are there?

Comment: In case of iodides I'd always prefer oxidizing them with $H_2O_2$ + acid to form iodine and then add hexane or heptane. Iodine will dye the non-polar layer purple.

Comment: @Justanotherchemist Thanks for your reply. I was looking for a more general method to identify should the compound be unknown.

Comment: Most methods are not that specific. Silver is quite useless it will precipitate with almost anything. For the fluoride and chloride I also like converting them to the corresponding $CrO2X2$. It's probably more uncommon but if simple halides are mixed with dichromates (toxic!) and conc. $H2SO4$ and heated it will form characteristic fumes and liquids that can be further tested for chromium using the peroxo-complex. If nothing else in there reacts with the dichromate I could probably distinguish fluoride from chloride. But it's quite dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

[ChemGuide](https://www.chemguide.co.uk/inorganic/group7/testing.html) gives another method:

> If you add concentrated sulphuric acid to a solid sample of one of the halides you get these results:
>   $$
> \begin{array}{c|c}
> \text{Ion present}&\text{Observation}\\\hline
> \ce{F-}&\text{steamy acidic fumes}\\
> \ce{Cl-}&\text{steamy acidic fumes}\\
> \ce{Br-}&\text{steamy acidic fumes contaminated with brown bromine vapour}\\
> \ce{I-}&\text{some steamy fumes, and lots of purple iodine vapour}\\
> \end{array}
> $$

Note that those "fumes" are of the corresponding hydrogen halides. Also, in the case of the iodide ion, "various red colours in the tube" are also observed.

This reaction occurs because concentrated sulphuric acid acts as an oxidizing agent. It isn't able to oxidize fluoride or chloride ions, but definitely oxidizes $\ce{Br-}$ and $\ce{I-}$ to $\ce{Br2}$ and $\ce{I2}$ respectively ([details here](https://www.chemguide.co.uk/inorganic/group7/halideions.html#top))

Do note that, to distinguish between the fumes of $\ce{HF}$ and $\ce{HCl}$ above, you'll need to dissolve them in water and perform the silver nitrate test!